# C# GUI DLL custom UserControl waste disk space

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, custom-controls, diskspace

I have created a GUI DLL that contain some UserControls.
One of the UserControls is a custom press button that use some images stored in a Resources.resx file. A user can set the color of button and I load the relative image

```
if(SelectedColor == GREEN)
  this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.greenButtonImage;
else if(SelectedColor == RED)
  this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.redButtonImage;
else
  ..
```

If I use the GUI DLL in a Form Project the initial size of the generated exe is 7KB
if I add my PressButtonControl the exe size of FormProject is 443 KB,
If a add another PressButtonControl the size is 889KB,
+ another PressButtonControl 1334KB,
+ another PressButtonControl the size is 1780 KB.

The images used in all controls is the same, why the space on disk is increasing?
Thank you

Comment: Is this a WPF question, UWP, WinForms?

Comment: Seems pretty clear you have ~445k of images in the UC.  It doesnt matter if they are the same, they are part of the control.

Comment: @GlenThomas is a WinForms application.

Comment: @Plutonix If I use 10 BLUE pressButtonControl the image is the same for all buttons, I dont want waste 4500KB, there is a way?

Comment: This is by design.  You need to replace the BackgroundImage property and give it the [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)] attribute so that the image doesn't get serialized into the form's .resx file.

Comment: @HansPassant If I use your tecnique the color of the button is not visible at runtime?
There is a way to have "static" image and all buttons that need the redButtonImage use the same image. I don't want make a copy of the same image for each button that I add to my form.